# Checking if a string isn't a space in Javascript

Tags: javascript

So I have a program that counts the words in a document that is loaded into an iFrame, all of the newline characters are replaced by a space, then the string is split by spaces, I then want to add them to a map as the key and set their value to 1 if they're not in the map or not a space, this is where I'm having the problem because it's still counting each space in the string , I feel like I'm being really stupid and missing something obvious...

```
var innerDoc = document.getElementById("pageinframe");
var innerDocContent = innerDoc.contentDocument.body.innerHTML;
var split = strip(innerDocContent).replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, " ").split(" ");
var obj = new Map();
for (var x = 0; x < split.length; x++) {
     console.dir(typeof split[x]);
     if(!obj.has(split[x]) && (split[x] != " ")) {
         obj.set(split[x], 1);
      }
      else if (split[x] != " ") {
         obj.set(split[x], obj.get(split[x])+1);
      }
}

function strip(str) {
    var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
    tmp.innerHTML = str;
    return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || "";
}
```

Comment: If you use 'split' doesn't it already give you an array of the words, without the space characters ?

Comment: Would it be easier to use `/\b/g` to find words ?

Answer (score 1):

There are something, icant understand. When you split(' '). the array not contains ' ', only words!!!, https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp. Son Why need to testif is white space. Then i think, it could be in:

```
.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

The split array contained "" not " " like I originally thought. Like I said I was missing something really obvious, just needed to see what was in the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
var innerDoc = document.getElementById("pageinframe");

var innerDocContent = innerDoc.contentDocument.body.innerHTML;

var split = strip(innerDocContent).replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, " ").split(" ");
var obj = new Map();
for (var x = 0; x < split.length; x++) {

     // Removing NaN for string
     if(split[x].charCodeAt(0))
     {
         if(!obj.has(split[x]) && (split[x] != " ")) {
             obj.set(split[x], 1);
          }
          else if (split[x] != " ") {
             obj.set(split[x], obj.get(split[x])+1);
          }
    }
}

function strip(str) {
    var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
    tmp.innerHTML = str;
    return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || "";
}

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: I hope this will help you :)